# How to set plugin for io.freefair.lombok

Tags: gradle, lombok, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the io.freefair.lombok plugin but I'm getting an error with Gradle 4.10.2. How do I set it?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "4.0.0" // error on this line
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeClasspath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\car-proj\build.gradle' line: 4
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.freefair.lombok', version: '5.0.0-rc4']
Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokBasePlugin']
Could not generate a proxy class for class io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.LombokExtension.
org/gradle/api/provider/MapProperty
org.gradle.api.provider.MapProperty
```

adding more text so post is not mostly code

Comment: The error message states version `5.0.0-rc4` being applied, but the `build.gradle` you posted lists version `4.0.0`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The version of the Lombok plugin you applied may not be compatible to your Gradle version. The [project website](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins) states that the latest version compatible to Gradle `4.10.2` is the `2.x` branch, specifically `2.9.5`. So either you use that or upgrade to a more recent Gradle version.

## Compatibility Matrix

| Plugin Version | Gradle Version | Java Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8.4.x | 8.4 | 8+ |
| 8.3.x | 8.3 | 8+ |
| 8.2.x | 8.2 | 8+ |
| 8.1.x | 8.1 | 8+ |
| 8.0.x | 8.0 | 8+ |
| 6.6.x | 7.6 | 8 - 18 |
| 6.5.x | 7.5 | 8 - 18 |
| 6.4.x | 7.4 | 8 - 17 |
| 6.3.x | 7.3 | 8 - 17 |
| 6.2.x | 7.2 | 8 - 16 |
| 6.1.x | 7.1 | 8 - 16 |
| 6.x | 7.0 | 8 - 16 |
| 5.3.x | 6.7 | 8 - 15 |
| 5.1.x | 6.4+ | 8 - 14 |
| 5.0.x | 6.3 | 8 - 13 |
| 4.x | 5.6+ | 8 - 12 |
| 3.8.x | 5.5.x | 8 - 12 |
| 3.3.x - 3.7.x | 5.4+ | 8 - 12 |
| 3.2.x | 5.3+ | 8 - 11 |
| 3.x | 5.1+ | 8 - 11 |
| 2.x | 4.x | 8 - 11 |

You may also want to upgrade Gradle to stay compatible to the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin.

> Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin requires Gradle 5.x or 6.x (4.10 is also supported but this support is deprecated and will be removed in a future release).

(From: [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#introduction))

**Update**

After reviewing your `build.gradle` more closely, you already have Lombok processing defined in your `dependencies` block:

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

You may use either this or the Lombok plugin. Both applied at the same time is not necessary.